# Verb + ed meaning in "I kissed her."

Tags: past-tense

I have learned that the ending 'ed' on a verb can be used for showing either of two grammatical conditions. It can show past tense or the completion of an action, as in 'this is finished.'

Which is applicable in the following sentence without any other context available?

> I kissed her.

Comment: The meaning, with or without context, is A - it is the past tense.  I don't know what you mean by 'completed action'.  That would be a murder, I suppose.

Comment: I don't even really understand what the question is.  You know what the past tense means, because you say it: something completed in the past.  I don't understand what the difference between A and B is supposed to be.

Comment: Does this mean action in the past or completed action in present

Comment: I don't understand "Does this mean action in the past or completed action in present".  Once an action is completed, how is it not in the past?

Answer (score 1):

The -ed ending on a verb indicates the simple past tense for regular verbs. Your sample sentence fits this description. Because it happened in the past, it's assumed that the action is complete, so there's really no difference between the past tense and a completed action.

If the action had not been completed you'd have to say something like

> I tried to kiss her.
> I almost kissed her.

The -ed ending could also indicate a past participle. Use of the past participle requires a form of 'to be' as a helping verb. You would use the past participle with a form of 'to be' to show a completed action, either completed in the past

> She was kissed.
> She has been kissed.
> She had been kissed.

or completed in the present.

> She is kissed.

Comment: Does this mean action in the past or completed action in present

Comment: Now I understand your question better. Please see my edits. If they answer your question you can remove the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In *I kissed her*, *kissed* is a verb and is in past tense.

How do we know? It's preceded by the subject pronoun *I*.

If it was preceded by a form of the word *to be*, or something else, then it might not be a verb.